# How can I extend Scala collections with an argmax method?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, extend

I would like to add to all collections where it makes sense, an [argMax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max) method.
How to do it? Use implicits?

Comment: A collection is not an expression. How can it have an argmax method? Are you trying to find the largest element in the collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Scala 2.8, this works:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)
def f(x: Int) = -x
val argMax = list max (Ordering by f)
```

As pointed by [mkneissl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158823/mkneissl), this does not return the *set* of maximum points. Here's an alternate implementation that does, and tries to reduce the number of calls to `f`. If calls to `f` don't matter that much, see [mkneissl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050557/how-can-i-extend-scala-collections-with-an-argmax-method/3053539#3053539). Also, note that his answer is curried, which provides superior type inference.

```
def argMax[A, B: Ordering](input: Iterable[A], f: A => B) = {
  val fList = input map f
  val maxFList = fList.max
  input.view zip fList filter (_._2 == maxFList) map (_._1) toSet
}

scala> argMax(-2 to 2, (x: Int) => x * x)
res15: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(-2, 2)
```

Comment: Fails if f reaches its max for multiple elements of its domain. Consider x=>x*x and x from -2 to 2

Comment: Sets are Iterable, but this does not work for Sets, most obviously not when f produces the same result for multiple elements.  The reason is that `input map f` produces another Set, which is now smaller than the input.  Thus the zip is desynchronized, and the wrong result is produced.  Even when the results of f are unique, the iteration order is not consistent, so the zip ends up scrambled.  Requiring the input to be a Seq fixes it.  If the need to do mySet.toSeq is undesirable, another solution is needed (e.g., one that does `input map {a=>(a,f(a)}` and so forth).

Answer (score 4):

The argmax function (as I understand it from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max))

```
def argMax[A,B](c: Traversable[A])(f: A=>B)(implicit o: Ordering[B]): Traversable[A] = {
  val max = (c map f).max(o)
  c filter { f(_) == max }
}
```

If you really want, you can pimp it onto the collections

```
implicit def enhanceWithArgMax[A](c: Traversable[A]) = new {
  def argMax[B](f: A=>B)(implicit o: Ordering[B]): Traversable[A] = ArgMax.argMax(c)(f)(o)
}
```

and use it like this

```
val l = -2 to 2
assert (argMax(l)(x => x*x) == List(-2,2))
assert (l.argMax(x => x*x) == List(-2,2))
```

(Scala 2.8)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the usual way would be to use the 'pimp my library' pattern to decorate your collection. For example (**N.B.** just as illustration, not meant to be a correct or working example):

```
trait PimpedList[A] {
   val l: List[A]

  //example argMax, not meant to be correct
  def argMax[T <% Ordered[T]](f:T => T) = {error("your definition here")}
}

implicit def toPimpedList[A](xs: List[A]) = new PimpedList[A] { 
  val l = xs
}

scala> def f(i:Int):Int = 10
f: (i: Int) Int

scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.argMax(f)
java.lang.RuntimeException: your definition here
    at scala.Predef$.error(Predef.scala:60)
    at PimpedList$class.argMax(:12)
        //etc etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

Nice and easy ? :

```
val l = List(1,0,10,2)
l.zipWithIndex.maxBy(x => x._1)._2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add functions to an existing API in Scala by using the [Pimp my Library](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) pattern. You do this by defining an implicit conversion function. For example, I have a class `Vector3` to represent 3D vectors:

```
class Vector3 (val x: Float, val y: Float, val z: Float)
```

Suppose I want to be able to scale a vector by writing something like: `2.5f * v`. I can't directly add a `*` method to class `Float` ofcourse, but I can supply an implicit conversion function like this:

```
implicit def scaleVector3WithFloat(f: Float) = new {
    def *(v: Vector3) = new Vector3(f * v.x, f * v.y, f * v.z)
}
```

Note that this returns an object of a structural type (the `new { ... }` construct) that contains the `*` method.

I haven't tested it, but I guess you could do something like this:

```
implicit def argMaxImplicit[A](t: Traversable[A]) = new {
    def argMax() = ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of doing so with the implicit builder pattern.  It has the advantage over the previous solutions that it works with any Traversable, and returns a similar Traversable.  Sadly, it's pretty imperative.  If anyone wants to, it could probably be turned into a fairly ugly fold instead.

```
object RichTraversable {
  implicit def traversable2RichTraversable[A](t: Traversable[A]) = new RichTraversable[A](t)
}

class RichTraversable[A](t: Traversable[A]) { 
  def argMax[That, C](g: A => C)(implicit bf : scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Traversable[A], A, That], ord:Ordering[C]): That = {
    var minimum:C = null.asInstanceOf[C]
    val repr = t.repr
    val builder = bf(repr)
    for(a<-t){
      val test: C = g(a)
      if(test == minimum || minimum == null){
        builder += a
        minimum = test
      }else if (ord.gt(test, minimum)){
        builder.clear
        builder += a
        minimum = test
      }
    }
    builder.result
  }
}

Set(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2).argmax(x=>x*x) == Set(-2, 2)
List(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2).argmax(x=>x*x) == List(-2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant loosely based on @Daniel's accepted answer that also works for Sets.

```
def argMax[A, B: Ordering](input: GenIterable[A], f: A => B) : GenSet[A] = argMaxZip(input, f) map (_._1) toSet

def argMaxZip[A, B: Ordering](input: GenIterable[A], f: A => B): GenIterable[(A, B)] = {
  if (input.isEmpty) Nil
  else {
    val fPairs = input map (x => (x, f(x)))
    val maxF = fPairs.map(_._2).max
    fPairs filter (_._2 == maxF)
  }
}
```

One could also do a variant that produces (B, Iterable[A]), of course.

Answer (score 0):

Based on other answers, you can pretty easily combine the strengths of each (minimal calls to `f()`, etc.). Here we have an implicit conversion for all Iterables (so they can just call `.argmax()` transparently), and a stand-alone method if for some reason that is preferred. ScalaTest tests to boot.

```
class Argmax[A](col: Iterable[A]) {
  def argmax[B](f: A => B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): Iterable[A] = {
    val mapped = col map f
    val max = mapped max ord
    (mapped zip col) filter (_._1 == max) map (_._2)
  }
}

object MathOps {
  implicit def addArgmax[A](col: Iterable[A]) = new Argmax(col)

  def argmax[A, B](col: Iterable[A])(f: A => B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]) = {
    new Argmax(col) argmax f
  }
}

class MathUtilsTests extends FunSuite {
  import MathOps._

  test("Can argmax with unique") {
    assert((-10 to 0).argmax(_ * -1).toSet === Set(-10))
    // or alternate calling syntax
    assert(argmax(-10 to 0)(_ * -1).toSet === Set(-10))
  }

  test("Can argmax with multiple") {
    assert((-10 to 10).argmax(math.pow(_, 2)).toSet === Set(-10, 10))
  }
}
```